# Split records based on multiple separator

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I am trying to prepare a query in PostgreSQL.

Below is my input:

[image]

Here you can find that in **Field column** has a unique value and **Values** column has values with multiple separators.

Now I want below output.

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. First value should be separated with **";"** and generate new column with **SplitFields**
2. From **Spitalfields** we have to again separate it with **">>"** and in that first value should be considered as **Folder** and Second Value should be considered as **Value**

How can I prepare the query?

I have prepared the same query in SQL server but in PostgreSQL, it didn't work for me as I have no idea about PostgreSQL.

Here is the query for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(1000)
SELECT
  @String = 'AV»ABC1; AC»ACTag; BB»BB1Tag; SampleInner»STag1; Not Privileged (RS)»Priv1tag; Winter 2015 Review»Windter1Tag'
SELECT
  *,
  LEFT(VALUE, CHARINDEX('»', VALUE) - 1) AS firstname,
  SUBSTRING(VALUE, CHARINDEX('»', VALUE) + 1, LEN(VALUE) - (CHARINDEX('»', VALUE) - 1)) AS lastname
FROM (SELECT
  SUBSTRING(';' + @String + ';', Number + 1,
  CHARINDEX(';', ';' + @String + ';', Number + 1) - Number - 1) AS VALUE
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE Type = 'P'
AND Number <= LEN(';' + @String + ';') - 1
AND SUBSTRING(';' + @String + ';', Number, 1) = ';') AS A
```

Comment: Isn't this simply a task of studying the [PostgreSQL documentation about string manipulation routines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)?

Comment: @UweKeim: I have read the documentation and also started preparing a query for same but I want an export who help me out to resolve it soon and meanwhile I am also preparing the query.

Comment: Sample data as formatted text is preferred over images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is way easier in Postgres. You first need to split the string by `;` to create the rows, then use `string_to_array()` to split up the second level

```
select field, 
       elements[1] as folder, 
       elements[2] as value
from (
   select t.field, "values", string_to_array(x.elements, '»') as elements
   from the_table t
      cross join unnest(string_to_array(t."values", ';')) as x(elements)
) x;
```

Or if you need to preserve the first level of "splitting":

```
select field, 
       splitfields,
       split_part(splitfields, '»', 1) as folder, 
       split_part(splitfields, '»', 2) as value 
from (
   select t.field, "values", x.splitfields
   from the_table t
      cross join unnest(string_to_array(t."values", ';')) as x(splitfields)
) x;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/IOW62752

Comment: Again I required your help, I require some modification, Can you please help me as per the updated question.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani: please do not change your question when you got an answer. Ask a new question instead (you can link back to this one)

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks, I will post new question

Comment: I have added a new question for that please find below link and your help will be really appreciated.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337599/split-records-based-on-multiple-separator-and-maintain-hierarchy